# Regular expression handlers within java

Tags: java, regex

Hi I have a series of regular expressions which I am trying to match to an input string. I want to then pass this string to a handler to complete some function on it based on what regular expression it matched. Is there an eloquent way to do this or is a series of if statements my best option?

Comment: Please show your attempt so far by adding code in the question

Comment: share some code so that we can help.

Answer (score 0):

You may probably combine your multiple regexps into single one like this: `(regex1)|(regex2)|...|(regexN)`.  Once combined regex matches, you may query `Matcher` object for what group is non-empty and choose function based on this.

Comment: Thanks a lot that is just what I was looking for